# How to remove for displaying format using @Html.DisplayFor in Asp.net Mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try to Display from my Data for removing Year using @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dob). This code is showing me "2020-11-18". but I don't need to see year for this displaying.I want to display like "11-18". it there simple way how to display without year in Asp.net Mvc?

Comment: what about `item.Dob.ToString("MMM dd");`

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: Are you passing the value as a string or a date ?

Comment: Data type is String.

Comment: I see. I can't say because I know nothing about your code, or table. But it's a little missy when using and storing the Date as a string. That being said, you can use a dirty solution like substring to remove the first 5 chars from your string and pass the rest to to the view.

Comment: Can you help me how to remove first 5 characters for displaying?

Comment: It's a very basic thing. Read about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thank you. but i am using @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dob.Substring(6, 5)) but I got error "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
  Source=System.Web.Mvc"

Comment: Format the string before pass it to the view. Or use another element to show the date in the view. Another thing to consider is if the month is a single number like 2, and the day is so as well. So you'll get an exception in this way. Use dob.Length as a second parameter.

Comment: My Dob Length is 10.so i made if statement like   @if (item.Dob.Length <= 8)
                    {
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dob.Substring(5,2))
                    }still same error for this code..

Comment: The main thing to say here is "don't use string fields to store dates". If you had used a proper DateTime field your problem would have been much simpler to solve. This data type exists for a reason

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform the operation beforehand.

This will do what you asked for:

```
@{
    string something = Model.Title.ToString().Substring(5, 2);
}
@Html.DisplayFor(x => something);
```

On a sidenote, you should not be using strings to store dates. Lookup DateTime and be amazed at all the built-in functionalities for manipulating and displaying date and time.